# Zod Conditional Requirements Based on Values in Array Field

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I have an Express route where I need to validate the request body using Zod. Based on the values in one of the fields (channels, which is an array of enums), I want to conditionally require other fields. My implementation works, but it is not very succinct. I appreciate any suggestions on a more succinct approach. I feel like there has to be one, but I have not been able to come up with one. I looked at discriminated union, but that appears to look at a field that has a single value, not an array of values.

The logic is...

- userId and channels are both always required.
- If channels includes the value "EMAIL", then the email-related fields should also be required.
- If channels includes the value "SMS", then the sms-related fields should also be required.
- If channels includes the value "FEED", then the feed-related fields should be required.
  My working approach...

```js
const schema = z.object({
  userId: z.string(),
  channels: z.array(z.enum(["EMAIL", "SMS", "FEED"])).nonempty(),
});

const emailSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string().nonempty().email(),
  firstName: z.string().nonempty(),
  lastName: z.string().nonempty(),
  emailSubject: z.string().nonempty(),
  emailText: z.string().nonempty(),
  emailHtml: z.string().nonempty(),
});

const smsSchema = z.object({
  phone: z.string().nonempty(),
  smsMessage: z.string().nonempty(),
});

const feedSchema = z.object({
  feedTitle: z.string().nonempty(),
  feedMessage: z.string().nonempty(),
});

const result = schema.safeParse(req.body);

if (!result.success) {
  const { message } = fromZodError(result.error);
  return res.status(400).json({
    error: { message },
  });
}

let channelsSchema = z.object({});

if (result.data.channels.includes("EMAIL"))
  channelsSchema = channelsSchema.merge(emailSchema);
if (result.data.channels.includes("SMS"))
  channelsSchema = channelsSchema.merge(smsSchema);
if (result.data.channels.includes("FEED"))
  channelsSchema = channelsSchema.merge(feedSchema);

const channelsResult = channelsSchema.safeParse(req.body);

if (!channelsResult.success) {
  const { message } = fromZodError(channelsResult.error);
  return res.status(400).json({
    error: { message },
  });
}

// do something with the data...
```

I have also seen some examples using refine and superRefine, but I feel like those may be even more lengthy and complex.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Approach #1: Unions

You could use `zod.refine` to ensure each type of message has the right `channel` flag, then use `zod.union` to create a union of all message types. Zod will try to parse each schema in the union and only throw an error if there are no matches.

For example:

```
const emailSchema = z.object({
  userId: z.string(),
  channels: z.array(z.string()).refine((val) => val.includes('EMAIL')),
  email: z.string().min(1).email(),
  firstName: z.string().nonempty(),
  lastName: z.string().nonempty(),
  emailSubject: z.string().nonempty(),
  emailText: z.string().nonempty(),
  emailHtml: z.string().nonempty(),
});

const smsSchema = z.object({
  userId: z.string(),
  channels: z.array(z.string()),
  phone: z.string().min(1),
  smsMessage: z.string().nonempty(),
});

const feedSchema = z.object({
  userId: z.string(),
  channels: z.array(z.string()),
  feedTitle: z.string().min(1),
  feedMessage: z.string().min(1),
});

const schema = z.union([
  emailSchema,
  smsSchema,
  feedSchema,
]);
```

## Approach #2: Custom Schema Switching

Alternatively, you could write some custom logic to use the right schemas based on the values in `channels`.

```
const messageSchema = z.object({
  userId: z.string(),
  channels: z.array(z.string()),
});

const emailSchema = messageSchema.extend({
  email: z.string().min(1).email(),
  firstName: z.string().nonempty(),
  lastName: z.string().nonempty(),
  emailSubject: z.string().nonempty(),
  emailText: z.string().nonempty(),
  emailHtml: z.string().nonempty(),
});

const smsSchema = messageSchema.extend({
  phone: z.string().min(1),
  smsMessage: z.string().nonempty(),
});

const feedSchema = messageSchema.extend({
  feedTitle: z.string().min(1),
  feedMessage: z.string().min(1),
});

function validateMessage(data: object) {
  const message = messageSchema.parse(data);
  
  if (message.channels.includes('EMAIL')) return emailSchema.parse(data);
  if (message.channels.includes('SMS')) return feedSchema.parse(data);
  if (message.channels.includes('FEED')) return feedSchema.parse(data);
}
```

## Comments

By the way, it's a little strange that the field that determines the shape of the object is an array. Typically a number or string field is used to denote an objects type to make the design simpler.

Comment: Thanks! As for the field, the API allows a client to create a notification and specify multiple channels, which is why we have the array. I ended up with something similar to your option 2.

Comment: I don't want to impose, but I would suggest having a structure like this to make implementation a lot easier and to separate concerns:

```json
const message = {
  userId: 'user-123',
  payloads: [
    {
      type: 'email',
      emailSubject: 'Example Email Field',
      emailText: 'Example email text',
      /* ... other email fields */
    },
    {
      type: 'sms',
      phone: '+15555555555',
      smsMessage: 'Example sms message',
    },
    {
      type: 'feed',
      feedTitle: 'Example Feed Title',
      feedMessage: 'Example FeedMessage',
    },
  ],
};
```